# Power BI sum multiple times from a relationship table

Tags: graph, powerbi, relationship

I have 2 tables on Power BI

Listened table:

[image]

Tracks:

[image]

Then I want to make a graph that shows per day the amount of minutes I've heard.
The problem is that, for instance, track #1 was listened 4 times, but it sums only once.

I've tried to create a relationship between tables in single and both direction but it didn't work properly.

Comment: what is your expected output? what is the breakdown of data in column "Played At"?

Comment: How did you sum the amount of minutes per day? You will have to use the COUNTROWS function with a FILTER.